# Manage.py cannot find package from other eclipse project

Tags: python, django, eclipse, import

I am developing several django apps in one eclipse project as well as a separate library on which some of the apps rely in another eclipse project. I have referenced the library project from my django project via `Properties->Project References`, which allows imports from one project into the other. These imports work exactly as expected when tested in a python console inside eclipse.

Now I try to start the development server of my django project in the Windows `cmd`-shell via `manage.py runserver`, but it fails with a message telling me it cannot find the aforementioned imports. I assume this is because the library which is under development is not "installed" anywhere for the script to find them.

What is the best solution for my problem?

Ideas and considerations:

- Could I run `manage.py runserver` from inside eclipse? Would that even solve the problem?
- I am working on both projects at the same time, so anything that introduces considerable overhead (like packing and installing the library after each edit) should be considered last.
- Is there a way to tell the manage.py script where to look for missing imports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me:

Adding `sys.path.append("relative\\path\\to\\library\\source\\folder")` after `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "djangoToolkit.settings")` did the trick. Because the source folder of my library project is now appended to the system path, the packages and modules of my library are now searched when starting the development server. My manage.py now looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "djangoToolkit.settings")
    sys.path.append("..\\LibraryProject\\src")
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```